# check for conflicts / student cannot Enroll twice in same course

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

If I have 3 tables

table called students (student_id,student_name)

students data: (1, john),(2, Mike),(3, Adam)

table called courses (course_id,course_name)

courses data: (1,math),(2,english),(3,science)

table called Enrollment (student_id,course_id)
enrollment data: (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),.....student cannot enroll twice in same course like (1,1),(1,1)

```
CREATE TABLE "enrollment" (
"student_id"    INTEGER,
"course_id" INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY("student_id") REFERENCES "students"("student_id"),
PRIMARY KEY("student_id","course_id"),
FOREIGN KEY("course_id") REFERENCES "courses"("course_id")
```

);

To enroll in a course:

I want to let the user enter student_id and based on student_id user enroll

When user enter course_id

my code:

```
 def enroll(student_id,course_id):

        dbase.execute(''' INSERT INTO enrollment(student_id,course_id)
                    VALUES(?,?)''',(student_id,course_id))
        dbase.commit()
        print("Record inserted")




  student_id = int(input('Enter student id: ')
  data = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id= ?",(student_id,))
  found = data.fetchone()
  if found:
      course_id = int(input("Enter the course id: "))
      if course_id >= 1 and course_id <= 3:
           enroll(student_id,course_id) 
      else:
           print('please try with valid course id!')
           main_menu()
   else:
       main_menu()
```

**student can't enroll twice in same course**
How can I fix this code?
I am using python/SQLite

Comment: A primary key would be formed on both columns of the enrolment table. Voila!

Comment: yes courses(student_id primary key), courses(course_id primary key) enrollment(student_id foreign key, course_id foreign key) but the problem in the code the student could enroll twice in the same course and that is wrong

Comment: No they couldn't, not if (student_id,course_id) is unique/primary

Comment: yes both are primary key and  foreign key

Comment: So, there you go

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a separate `enrollment` table for setting `course_id` for a student, just add `course_id` field to `students` table. But if you need a separate table, just add a unique constraint on `student_id` field, add the following line to create table `enrollment` script, or alter that table

```
CONSTRAINT uc_student_id UNIQUE (student_id)
```